# How to disable grouped checkboxes while keeping the clicked one enable?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have a group of check boxes with same class name, I want to disable the rest when one is clicked and keep the clicked one enable. I have tried the solution here: [disable other checkboxes when one with similar class is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539917/disable-other-checkboxes-when-one-with-similar-class-is-clicked)

However the solution does not work for me and I can't figure out why.

HTML

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks" class="group"> JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="express" class="group"> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
```

Script

```
$(".group").change(() => {
  console.log("hitting the check box");
  this.checked ? $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", true) : $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", false);
})
```

there is no error, and I hit the console.log every time i click but nothing happens. I have tried both change() and click() with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you needed to care about was -- `this` wasn't what you expected in [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). Convert the arrow function to a regular function.

```js
$(".group").change(function() {
  console.log("hitting the check box");
  this.checked ? $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", true) : $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="js-frameworks" class="group"> JavaScript Frameworks Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="express" class="group"> Express Workshop — Tuesday 9am-12pm, $100</label>
```