# Disable other checkboxes when checkbox with the same sales code is already checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frontend, web-frontend

Can someone help me with this one?

[image]

I have this list in my table with checkbox. As you can see there are duplicate sales code.

What I'm trying to do is that if I check one row, the other checkbox row with similar sales code should be disabled like this. And then i should also be able to check other rows with different sales code.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable other checkboxes when one with similar class is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539917/disable-other-checkboxes-when-one-with-similar-class-is-clicked)

Comment: @Don'tPanic hi yes, i found this answer while waiting for some inputs yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`disabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) property of your other `HTMLInputElements` (your checkboxes) to the current [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#checked) state in an [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event listener. Here's a code sample with `optionA` and `optionB` as the checkboxes:

```js
optionA.addEventListener('input', () => {
    optionB.disabled = optionA.checked;
});
optionB.addEventListener('input', () => {
    optionA.disabled = optionB.checked;
});
```

Every time a user checks or unchecks a checkbox, it raises the corresponding event. If the checked state is `true`, set the disabled property on the other checkbox to `true`. If the checked state is `false`, or unchecked, set the disabled property on the other checkbox to `false` to re-enable it.

Answer (score 0):

Need more details on how you are rendering your HTML as well.
What you can do is, add an event listener for your checkbox (may be based on class name), but add your custom attribute to the checkbox as well and assign your sales code value to that custom attribute

I've added a working code snippet, you can improve it according to your needs

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".salesCodeChk").change(function(){
       var salesCode = $(this).attr("sales-code");  
       $(".salesCodeChk").prop("disabled", false);
       if(this.checked){
          
          $("[sales-code='" + salesCode + "']").not(this).prop("disabled",true);
       }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="salesCodeChk" sales-code="ISK12345"/>ISK12345</br>
<input type="checkbox" class="salesCodeChk" sales-code="ISK12345"/>ISK12345</br>
<input type="checkbox" class="salesCodeChk" sales-code="ISK123456"/>ISK123456
```